# How can i modify parameterMap values using HttpServletRequestWrapper ?

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets, http-request-parameters

I have a web application designed to play the role of a search engine. Its backend is developed in Java and its frontend in angularJS.
I have the following class named PrettyFacesWrappedRequest that i found on the following link with some explanations : [link here](https://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/how-to-safely-add-modify-servlet-request-parameter-values/)

```
public class PrettyFacesWrappedRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper{
private final Map<String, String[]> modifiableParameters;
private Map<String, String[]> allParameters = null;

/**
 * Create a new request wrapper that will merge additional parameters into
 * the request object without prematurely reading parameters from the
 * original request.
 * 
 * @param request
 * @param additionalParams
 */
public PrettyFacesWrappedRequest(final HttpServletRequest request, 
                                                final Map<String, String[]> additionalParams)
{
    super(request);
    modifiableParameters = new TreeMap<String, String[]>();
    modifiableParameters.putAll(additionalParams);
}

@Override
public String getParameter(final String name)
{
    String[] strings = getParameterMap().get(name);
    if (strings != null)
    {
        return strings[0];
    }
    return super.getParameter(name);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap()
{
    if (allParameters == null)
    {
        allParameters = new TreeMap<String, String[]>();
        allParameters.putAll(super.getParameterMap());
        allParameters.putAll(modifiableParameters);
    }
    //Return an unmodifiable collection because we need to uphold the interface contract.
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(allParameters);
}

@Override
public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames()
{
    return Collections.enumeration(getParameterMap().keySet());
}

@Override
public String[] getParameterValues(final String name)
{
    return getParameterMap().get(name);
}
```

}

My aim is to inject the code below in order to manage any http request coming from any other application. For example, i have this following html form where i want to search for a word:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

</head>
<body>

 <form action="http://localhost:8050/Babel/#/search" method="GET" enctype="application/json">
  <input type="text" name="word" id="word">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" >
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I implemented a class where i retrieve the word parameter through the referer of the request header (request.getHeader("referer")) and triming the string down by splitting it up into substring divided by the "=" character.

Here is the code below :

```
public class ControllerTemplate<T extends SearchResponse> {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerTemplate.class);
private static final String X_REQUESTED_WITH = "X-Requested-With";
private static final String XML_HTTP_REQUEST = "XMLHttpRequest";
protected Identification identification;
protected SearchApiUseCase<T> useCase;
protected ObjectMapper mapper;
protected ControllerTemplate(SearchApiUseCase<T> useCase, Identification identification) {//        if(useCase == null || identification == null){
    if(useCase == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("ControllerTemplate construct error");
    }
    this.useCase = useCase;//        this.identification = identification;
    this.identification = null;
    this.mapper = new ObjectMapper();
}
private final ResponseEntity<?> constructResponseEntity(int httpStatusCode, String msg){
    ObjectNode object = mapper.createObjectNode();
    object.put("message",msg);
    object.put("timestamp", Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    return ResponseEntity.status(httpStatusCode).body(object.toString());
}
private final void isAjaxHttpRequest(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) throws HttpSearchErrorException{
    if(httpRequest.getHeader(X_REQUESTED_WITH) == null || !XML_HTTP_REQUEST.equalsIgnoreCase(httpRequest.getHeader(X_REQUESTED_WITH))){
        throw new HttpBadRequestSearchErrorException("X-Requested-With is missing");
    }
}
private final void isUserAuthenticated() throws SearchErrorException{
    identification.checkIdentity();
}
@RequestMapping(produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = {RequestMethod.GET})
@ResponseBody
public final ResponseEntity<?> research(@RequestParam(required = true, name ="word") String word,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "1", name = "page") int page,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "5", name = "maxrow") int maxRow,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "", name = "filter") String filter, HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException{
    ResponseEntity<?> response = null;
    System.out.println("word : " + word);
    try{
        isAjaxHttpRequest(request);//            isUserAuthenticated();
        System.out.println("the request is " + request.getQueryString());
        System.out.println("Request headers : " + request.getHeader("referer"));
        String referer = request.getHeader("referer");
        String externalWord = referer.split("=")[1];
        if(!(externalWord.equals("")) && (word.equals(""))){
            word = externalWord;
            page = 1;
            maxRow = 5;
            filter = "";
            Map<String, String[]> extraParams = new TreeMap<String, String[]>();
            String[] param1 = {externalWord};
            String[] param2 = {"1"};
            String[] param3 = {"5"};
            extraParams.put("word", param1);
            extraParams.put("page", param2);
            extraParams.put("maxrow", param3);
            HttpServletRequest wrappedRequest = new PrettyFacesWrappedRequest(request, extraParams);
            RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
            HttpServletResponse responseServ = ((ServletRequestAttributes)requestAttributes).getResponse();             request.getRequestDispatcher("http://localhost:8050/Babel/#/search").forward(wrappedRequest, responseServ);
        }
        SearchResponse resultat = useCase.resultUseCase(word, page, maxRow, filter, null);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        response = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).headers(headers).body(resultat.getSearchSources());
    }catch(HttpSearchErrorException e){
        LOGGER.error("{HttpSearchErrorException}",e);
        response = constructResponseEntity(e.getHttpStatus(), e.getMessage());
    }catch(SearchErrorException e){
        LOGGER.error("{SearchErrorException}",e);
        response = constructResponseEntity(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.value(), e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println("Response : " + response.toString());
    return response;
}
```

}

The research function normally returns a list of search results when the word is provided as a parameter. Since the web application can't modify the request parameterMap, the function doesn't return any result.

I have been trying to trying to find a solution or a workaround for this problem a long time ago. Any help would be much appreciated. I will even provided additional code snippet if needed. Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: 'word' is a request parameter (query param of your 'get' action). Why are you extracting it from the header?